# bootstrap modal send multiple ajax request includes previous successfull ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

My code

```
   $("#lead-list .selectboxit").on("change", function() {
    var st = $( this ).val();
    var eid = $(this).attr("id");
    var id_ar = eid.split("-");
    if(st)
    {
        $(".modal-body").html("<p>Are you sure to change the status of the records?</p>");
        $('#modal-1').modal('show');
        $("#modal-1 .confirm-continue").click(function(event){
            $('#modal-1').modal('hide');
            jQuery.ajax({     
                type: "POST",
                url: 'ajax-listing-lead-process.php',
                data: {val: st,id: id_ar[1], action:'update'},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data)
                        alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I've many select dropdown with id like **status-1, status-2, status-3,...etc**.
if I change **status-1**, then it send ajax request with its values.after that i change **status-2**, it send ajax request for **status-1 and also status-2 with its respective values**. further changing **status-3**, it send ajax request for **status-1, status-2 and status-3 with its respective values**.

How to send ajax request only for currently changed element value and avoid resending previous ajax requests.

`note: It works fine without modal-confirmation dialogue box.`

Comment: From your jQuery - You have put a change event on the Class attribute - '.selectboxit' - So If I am understanding you correctly you have 3 dropdowns with the same class attribute. - So that is why it is sending three requests when you change status-3

Comment: You could try this: $("#lead-list .selectboxit").on("change", function(e) { e.stopPropagation();    var st = $( this ).val(); ........

Comment: for example if I change dropdown for 3rd time. onchange event is not triggering 3 times. only code inside '$("#modal-1 .confirm-continue").click(' is executed 3 times.

Comment: Yes because you are binding the click event against .confirm-continue 3 times. 1 - when you change status-1, 2. when you change status-2 and then 3 - when you change status-3, you execute this:  $("#modal-1 .confirm-continue").click(function(event){

Comment: @DawoodAwan how to solve this?

Comment: I am not sure - Try: $("#modal-1 .confirm-continue").click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation();

Comment: it stops after executing 1st request. unfortunately the 1st request is old one(previous request). current request excuted at last.